# Zoom multiple objects simultaneously in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I have a UIScrollview that contains multiple UIImageViews. I could zoom using the UIScrollView delegate but can only return one UIImageView at a time. I want to be able to zoom all objects inside the scrollview simultaneously when i try to zoom the uiscrollview. How can I achieve this?

This is what my delegate returns when zooming:

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your image views into one single UIView, which in turn is inside the UIScrollView. Then return your UIView as the view to zoom. Since the image views are inside it, they'll get zoomed as well.